# Unable to install python-poppler on Windows

Tags: python-3.x, poppler

I tried to open and read a PDF portfolio through Python and found that python-poppler will do the work. However, I got stuck during the installation of the module.

I did the following steps to install the module. However, it gives me an error message.

1. Install cmake through pip: pip install cmake
2. Install python-poppler through pip: pip install --use-pep517 python-poppler. Get the error:

```
Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [20 lines of output]
      + meson setup C:\Users\A460399\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-bu1qyb0s\python-poppler_d5b667c6719e42f190c6e4a8ec5ab898 C:\Users\A460399\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-bu1qyb0s\python-poppler_d5b667c6719e42f190c6e4a8ec5ab898\.mesonpy-tddgg1_x -Dbuildtype=release -Db_ndebug=if-release -Db_vscrt=md --native-file=C:\Users\A460399\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-bu1qyb0s\python-poppler_d5b667c6719e42f190c6e4a8ec5ab898\.mesonpy-tddgg1_x\meson-python-native-file.ini
      The Meson build system
      Version: 1.3.2
      Source dir: ..\Temp\pip-install-bu1qyb0s\python-poppler_d5b667c6719e42f190c6e4a8ec5ab898
      Build dir: ..\Temp\pip-install-bu1qyb0s\python-poppler_d5b667c6719e42f190c6e4a8ec5ab898\.mesonpy-tddgg1_x
      Build type: native build
      Project name: python-poppler
      Project version: 0.4.1
      WARNING: Failed to activate VS environment: Could not parse vswhere.exe output
     
      ..\meson.build:1:0: ERROR: Unknown compiler(s): [['icl'], ['cl'], ['c++'], ['g++'], ['clang++'], ['clang-cl']]
      The following exception(s) were encountered:
      Running `icl ""` gave "[WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified"
      Running `cl /?` gave "[WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified"
      Running `c++ --version` gave "[WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified"
      Running `g++ --version` gave "[WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified"
      Running `clang++ --version` gave "[WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified"
      Running `clang-cl /?` gave "[WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified"
     
      A full log can be found at ..\Temp\pip-install-bu1qyb0s\python-poppler_d5b667c6719e42f190c6e4a8ec5ab898\.mesonpy-tddgg1_x\meson-logs\meson-log.txt
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
```

3. I tried install through Git and got the same error message above.

Now, I'm very lost and confused about how to correctly install this module. I'm working on my work laptop, so it doesn't allow me to change any environment paths. I've gone through almost all the solutions that I could find online, but I might have missed some other solutions. Please let me know if there's a solution available on Stack Overflow that I missed. Also, inform me if I need to improve the question or provide any screenshots or additional information.